# Let $A$ be the matrix of $T:P_2\to P_2$ with respect to basis $B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. Find $T(v_1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $A$ be the matrix of $T:P_2\to P_2$ with respect to basis $B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. Find $T(v_1)$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & -1 \\
2 & 0 & 5 \\
6 & -2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

$v_1=3x+3x^2$

$v_2=-1+3x+2x^2$

$v_3=3+7x+2x^2$

---

First part of question asks to find $T(v_1)_B$.

$$T(v_1)_B=[T]_{P_2}^{B}\cdot (v_1)_{P_2}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & -1 \\
2 & 0 & 5 \\
6 & -2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
3  \\
3 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
6  \\
15  \\
6
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $v_1$ is our vector, $B$ is the basis, $P_2=\{1,x,x^2\}$, $A=[T]_{P_2}^{B}$

Assuming I did this part of the question correct, now the next part asks be to find $T(v_1)$, with respect to **no basis**.

---

I think this makes sense: since we already found $T(v_1)_B$, that means that the vector $[6,15,6]$ can be written as a linear combinations of the vectors in the basis $B$. Hence we have:

$$6+15x+6x^2=r_1(3x+3x^2)+r_2(-1+3x+2x^2)+r_3(3+7x+2x^2)$$

Cleaning up a bit we get:

$$6+15x+6x^2=(-r_2+3r_3)1+(3r_1+3r_2+7r_3)x+(3r_1+2r_2+2r_3)x^2$$

Giving us the solution set:

$$\color{red}{-r_2+3r_3=5}, \color{green}{3r_1+3r_2+7r_3=15}, \color{blue}{3r_1+2r_2+2r_3=6}$$

Solving for $r_1,r_2,r_3$, we should have $T(v_1)$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did the first part incorrectly. It looks like where you tripped up is that $A=[T]_B^B$, not $[T]_{P_2}^B$. $[v_1]_B=[1,0,0]$, so $[Tv_1]_B$ is just the first column of $A$ (and similarly for $v_2$ and $v_3$. This is a handy property to remember: in general, the columns of the matrix of a linear transformation are the images of the basis vectors, expressed relative to the “output” basis.

That aside, you also computed the basis conversion in the wrong direction. If you have $[w]_B=[a,b,c]$, this means that $w=av_1+bv_2+cv_3$, so to recover the polynomial that corresponds to $[Tv_1]_B$, you simply need to compute this linear combination.

Comment: I understand your second paragraph, but in your first, you say that the columns of the matrix of a lin trans are the images of the BASIS vectors, expressed RELATIVE to the "OUTPUT" basis, in this case the output is $P_2$, is it not? you did both $B$

Comment: @KSplitX “Let $A$ be the matrix ... with respect to basis $B$” means that $B$ is both the *input* and *output* basis. $P_2$ isn’t a basis, anyway, it’s a vector space of polynomials. Multiplying a vector of reals by $A$ produces another vector of reals, not a polynomial of any sort.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah I was confused as to what the input and output basis would be since only $B$ was mentioned, so I assumed the output basis to be the basis of $P_2=\{1,x,x^2\}$

Answer (score 0):

$T(v_1) = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\6 \end{bmatrix}$

This is still represented in terms of the the basis B.

If we want to then represent this vector with respect to the canonical basis.

$v_1 + 2v_2 + 6v_3  = (3x + 3x^2) + 2(-1 + 3x + 2x^2) + 6(3 + 7x  + 2x^2)$

or

$\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1&3\\3&3&7\\3&2&2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\6 \end{bmatrix}$